# How do I prevent text overflow when using savebox?

Tags: environments, boxes

I want to create a custom Definition environment. The environment should use some local commands to declare logical parts of the definition (e.g. assumptions using a command `Let`). The definition text should be plain text (not wrapped in a command).

I want to store and process all information in the end group of the environment (e.g. for dynamic formatting). For the definition text, I'm using the savebox command within the begin group of the environment.

My problem is: when I simply use `\usebox` in the environment's end group the box overflows and some content is cut off. How can I prevent or work around this?

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\DefinitionLet}[3][]{%
}
\newsavebox{\DefinitionContentBox}

\newenvironment{Definition}[1][]{%
    \let\Let\DefinitionLet%
    \def\DefinitionName{#1}
    \savebox{\DefinitionContentBox}\bgroup%
}{%
    \egroup%
    \noindent (Definition) \DefinitionName\\
    \newline\usebox{\DefinitionContentBox}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{Definition}[Definition A]
\Let{$A$}{some set}
\Let{$a$}{element of $A$}
\lipsum[100]
\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Using a box will make dynamic formatting impossible (unless you `\unbox` instead of `\usebox`). I think you're interested to the `environ` package.

Comment: `\unbox` is an undefined command. Do I need a package?

Comment: Sorry, `\unhbox`; but you should make clearer what you have in mind: I don't see any real advantage in storing the environment's content, as the typesetting parameters can be set in the “begin” part. By the way, note that `\savebox{<box bin>}\bgroup` is not really supported.

Comment: `\savebox{\DefinitionContentBox}\bgroup%` is absolutely not supported syntax!!! Use the `lrbox` environment.

Comment: @egreg Basically I want to be able to rearrange the logical parts of the definition (e.g. assumptions and text). More specifically I want to display the contents of the `Let` commands in a list (above or below the definition text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an `\unhbox` approach as suggested by egreg in the comments.  What `\unhbox` allows is for formatting to be applied around the formerly boxed material.  So, for instance, here, I place the content in an `\fbox`ed `\parbox`.  I could just as easily settled for an `\unhbox\DefinitionContentBox` which would just set the boxed content with the prevailing margin formatting.

EDITED to use `lrbox` instead of `\hbox\bgroup...\egroup` (thanks, David).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\DefinitionLet}[3][]{%
}
\newsavebox{\DefinitionContentBox}

\newenvironment{Definition}[1][]{%
    \let\Let\DefinitionLet%
    \def\DefinitionName{#1}
    \begin{lrbox}{\DefinitionContentBox}%
}{%
    \end{lrbox}\noindent (Definition) \DefinitionName\\
    \newline\fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\unhbox\DefinitionContentBox}}
    \par\bigskip
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Definition}[Definition A]
\Let{$A$}{some set}
\Let{$a$}{element of $A$}
\lipsum[100]
\end{Definition}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup%` is not supported syntax and will do completely the wrong thing if colour is being used. `lrbox` environment was introduced for this use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thanks for that reminder.  Fixed.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Great!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `\unhbox` and not `\usebox`: the difference is that the latter delivers the contents of the box, rather than the box itself. However, this is not the method I recommend, unless you have verbatim material in the body of the environment.

I would use `environ` for this purpose:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\DefinitionLet}[3][]{}

\NewEnviron{Definition}[1][]{%
  \let\Let\DefinitionLet 
  \def\DefinitionName{#1}%
  \par\bigskip\noindent (Definition) \DefinitionName\\*
  \fbox{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{\BODY}%
  }%
  \par\bigskip
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[200]

\begin{Definition}[Definition A]
\Let{$A$}{some set}
\Let{$a$}{element of $A$}
\lipsum[100]
\end{Definition}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Limitations of the `\unhbox` approach

Language attributes are ignored, in the sense that setting `\language=<number>` (via `\foreignlanguage` or similar method) in the environment will not work.

### Limitations of the `environ` approach

You can't include verbatim material in the body of the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Saveboxes are LR boxes (like `\mbox` or `\fbox`) whose contents will not be broken across lines. Text to be typeset in paragraph mode must be placed into `\parboxes` or `minipages` which know (from their required arguments) how long lines will finally be in order to be able to place line breaks properly.

Why don't you just say:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\DefinitionLet}[3][]{%
}

\newenvironment{Definition}[1][]{%
    \let\Let\DefinitionLet%
    \def\DefinitionName{#1}
    \noindent (Definition) \DefinitionName\\
    \newline
}{}%

\begin{document}
\begin{Definition}[Definition A]
\Let{$A$}{some set}
\Let{$a$}{element of $A$}
\lipsum[100]
\end{Definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I explain why I don't do this in the comment above.